# Angular material floating label text is cutting

Tags: css, angular, sass, overflow, typescript-typings

I am uaing angular material components while loading the fields floating feature is working fine but After ajaxcall and append the HTML response to specific div tag floating notch width caluclating not properly.After getting the response in Ajaxcall one CORS error logged in windsows console section. I am not sure it's an issue with CORS error i mean CORS error stopping CSS loading either DOM loading issue.

**Textbox.TS**
'''

```
public intializeElements = (): void => {
    const textFields1 = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field'), function (el) {
        return new MDCTextField(el);
    });
    const helperTexts1 = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field-helper-text'), function (el) {
        return new MDCTextFieldHelperText(el);
    });
    this.initializeLabelPosition();
    this.listenOnValidationAttributeChange();
    this._jQueryValidationExtension.setupShowErrors(this.showErrorCallback);
}

private listenOnChromeAutoFillPrefill = (): void => {
    var outlinedTextbox = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('input.mdc-text-field__input:not(.phone-otp-phone-number-field__input').each(function () {
            var elem = $(this);
            if (elem.val() || elem.is(":-webkit-autofill")) {
                outlinedTextbox.floatLabelAbove(this);
            }
        })
    }, 500);
}

public initializeLabelPosition = (): void => {
    var outlinedTextbox = this;

    $('input.mdc-text-field__input:not(.phone-otp-phone-number-field__input)').each(function () {
         // check for initial value and autofill's prefill feature
    if (!$(elem).val() && !$(elem).is(":-webkit-autofill")) return;
    this.floatLabelAboveWithoutInputCheck(elem);
        });
    $('div.mdc-text-field-helper-line').hide();
}

public listenOnValidationAttributeChange = (): void => {
    var _outlinedTextBox = this;
    $('input.mdc-text-field__input:not(.phone-otp-phone-number-field__input)').attrchange(function (source, id, value) {
        if (source == "aria-invalid") {
            _outlinedTextBox._validationStatus.setValidationStatus(id, value, $(this)[0].name);
        }
    });

    // for text box focus out
    $('label.mdc-text-field:not(.phone-otp-phone-number-field)').attrchange(function (source, id, value) {
        if (source == "class") {
            if (value.indexOf("mdc-text-field--focused") === -1) {
                _outlinedTextBox._validationStatus.setValidationStatus(id, _outlinedTextBox._validationStatus.isInvalid(id));
            }
        }
    });

    $('span.phone-otp-helper-text').attrchange(function (source, id, value) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("field-validation-error")) {
            $(this).removeClass("field-validation-error");
        }
    });
}
public floatLabelAboveWithoutInputCheck = (elem: HTMLElement): void => {
    var $label = $(elem).parent();
    var $notchOutline = $label.children(".mdc-notched-outline");
    var $notch = $notchOutline.children(".mdc-notched-outline__notch");
    var $floatingLabel = $notchOutline.children(".mdc-notched-outline__notch").children(".mdc-floating-label");

    if (!$floatingLabel.hasClass("mdc-floating-label--float-above")) $floatingLabel.addClass("mdc-floating-label--float-above");
    if (!$label.hasClass("mdc-text-field--label-floating")) $label.addClass("mdc-text-field--label-floating");
    if (!$notchOutline.hasClass("mdc-notched-outline--notched")) $notchOutline.addClass("mdc-notched-outline--notched");
    var notchWidth = this.getFloatingLabelWidth($floatingLabel) / 1.3333 + 8;
    $notch.css("width", notchWidth.toString());
}

private getFloatingLabelWidth = ($elem: JQuery<HTMLElement>): number => {
    var html_org = $elem.html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $elem.html(html_calc);
    var width = $elem.find('span:first').width();
    $elem.html(html_org);
    return width;
};'''
```

**Ajax Action**

```
getCaptcha= (userAction): any => {
    let self = this;
    let $form = this._form.$form;
    var clientQueryString = self.getClientQueryString();
    this._httpClient.sendHttpRequestAsync(
        HttpMethod.Get,
        `getCaptcha?userAction=${userAction}&${clientQueryString}`,
        false,
        DataType.Text,
        ContentType.FormUrlEncoded,
        null,
        this.getCsrfInHeader($form)
    ).then(response => {
        var strResponse = response.toString();
        if (strResponse.startsWith('{')) {
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.toString());
            if (typeof jsonResponse?.data?.status === 'boolean' && !jsonResponse.data.status) {
                $form.find('.cpt-section').html('');
                this._form.showError(jsonResponse?.data?.messages);
            }
        } else {
            $form.find('.cpt-section').html(strResponse);
            
        }
    })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('Get Department: ', err);
        });
}
```

**TextBox Response HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix captcha-container">
<label for="imageText_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" class="mdc-text-field text-field mdc-text-field--outlined phone-otp-label">
    <input id="imageText_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="lblImage_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" aria-describedby="captchaHelperText_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" aria-controls="captchaHelperText_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-regex="The characters entered do not match the image. Please enter the characters that appear in the image, in order to proceed." data-val-regex-pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,7})$" data-val-required="Please enter the characters that appear in the image, in order to proceed." name="ImageText" value="" />
    <span class="mdc-notched-outline">
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></span>
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__notch">
            <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="lblImage_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87">Enter the text displayed above</span>
        </span>
        <span class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></span>
    </span>
</label>
<div class="mdc-text-field-helper-line phone-otp-helper-line">
    <span class="mdc-text-field-helper-text mdc-text-field-helper-text--validation-msg phone-otp-helper-text field-validation-valid" id="captchaHelperText_abba3833-398b-4703-94e6-a72bd48aed87" aria-hidden="true" data-valmsg-for="ImageText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

After loading textbox display like below.
[image]

When we focuse on the text box it's display like below.
[image]